# Android: custom view with TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER keyboard (IME) - input doesn't work

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-keypad

I faced with a strange keyboard behaviour, when I setup the keyboard type to TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER.

I use BaseInputConnection to connect my editable object and TextWathcer to listen of any text changes.

The problem:

1. When the inputType=TYPE_CLASS_TEXT and first input symbol is any
   symbol except the number - all works fine and editable text changes.
2. When I switch the keyboard type to TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER and trying to
   enter numbers  - nothing changes.

For example:

1. Input "12345"  Output ""
2. Input "teststring123" Output "teststring123" ,
3. Input "123teststring" Output "teststring"

Full Code:

```
public class CustomView extends View implements View.OnClickListener {

private Editable editable;

private InputMethodManager imm;

private final CustomTextWatcher textWatcher = new CustomTextWatcher();

private Paint mainPaint;

private int batch;

public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context, null);
}

public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs);
}

public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context, attrs);
}

private void init(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {

    setOnClickListener(this);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    editable = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable("");
    editable.setSpan(textWatcher, 0, editable.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    Selection.setSelection(editable, 0);


    mainPaint = new Paint();
    mainPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
    mainPaint.setTextSize(30);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawText(editable.toString(), 15, 20, mainPaint);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    imm.showSoftInput(this, 0);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && batch == 0) {
        int cursorPosition = 0;

        imm.viewClicked(this);
        imm.updateSelection(this, cursorPosition, cursorPosition, cursorPosition, cursorPosition);
        imm.updateSelection(this, cursorPosition, cursorPosition, -1, -1);
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
    Log.e("CustomView", " onCreateInputConnection");

    outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER;
    outAttrs.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE;
    outAttrs.initialSelStart = 0;
    outAttrs.initialSelEnd = 0;

    return new BaseInputConnection(this, true) {
        @Override
        public Editable getEditable() {
            return editable;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean endBatchEdit() {
            batch++;
            return super.endBatchEdit();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean beginBatchEdit() {
            batch--;
            return super.beginBatchEdit();
        }
    };
}

@Override
public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {
    return true;
}


private class CustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        Log.e("CustomView",  "afterTextChanged " + s);
        invalidate();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found the solution, that works for me.

For handling numbers from IME and passing them to the editable object, through InputConnection, all you need to do the following:

Implement "sendKeyEvent" method as shown below

```
    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {

    outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER;
    outAttrs.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE;
    outAttrs.initialSelStart = 0;
    outAttrs.initialSelEnd = 0;

    return new BaseInputConnection(this, true) {

        @Override
        public Editable getEditable() {
            return editable;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean endBatchEdit() {
            batch++;
            return super.endBatchEdit();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean beginBatchEdit() {
            batch--;
            return super.beginBatchEdit();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean sendKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN 
                     && event.getKeyCode() >= KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0 
                     && event.getKeyCode() <= KeyEvent.KEYCODE_9) {
                char c = event.getKeyCharacterMap().getNumber(event.getKeyCode());
                commitText(String.valueOf(c), 1);
            }
            return super.sendKeyEvent(event);
        }
     };
 }
```